# Превращение синхронного кода в асинхронный python

Tags: python, asyncio

Я очень часто использую асинхронность в python, но обычно всё сводится к вызовам асинхронных функций в каких-либо библиотеках (например `aiohttp`).

Меня уже давно мучает вопрос: **как синхронный код превращается в асинхронный**? Я знаю про планировщик, корутины, генераторы и т.д, но не могу понять как всё это работает изнутри и как я могу асинхронно ожидать выполнения синхронной функции.

**Кратко о задаче**: нужно асинхронно сделать запрос в базу. Конечно, есть асинхронные библиотеки, но для примера предположим, что таковых не нашлось

```
async def foo():
    ...
    cursor.execute(query)  # Синхронная функция, которая посылает запрос
```

Как я с помощью `asyncio` я могу сказать *"Подожди пока эта функция выполнится, а пока делай что-нибудь другое"*.

Comment: Указать `asyncio`, что нужно это выполнять в отдельном потоке `await asyncio.to_thread(cursor.execute, query)`.